# List comprehension of namedtuples results in empty list

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, list-comprehension, namedtuple

I've stumbled upon a problem I just can't seem to find an answer for. I am reading the contents of a csv file using `csv.DictReader` and constructing a list of namedtuples from that information. However, upon running it, the end result is an empty list.

```
from collections import namedtuple
import csv

nt = namedtuple('suminfo', 'a, b, c')
checklist = ['check1', 'check2', 'check3']

with open('test.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
     csv_rows = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter='\t')
     tups = [nt(row['first'], row['second'], row['third']) 
            for row in csv_rows if row['first'] in checklist]
```

I have also tried a typical normal loop of the rows followed by list appending of a namedtuple, and this seems to work just fine.

Why is the listcomprehension not behaving as expected? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list comprehension is working for me. I used this test data (test.csv):

```
first   second  third
check1  1   1
check2  2   2
check3  3   3
check4  4   4
```

The values are separated by tabs. When I run your code,

```
nt = namedtuple('suminfo', 'a, b, c')
checklist = ['check1', 'check2', 'check3']

with open('test.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_rows = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter='\t')
    tups = [nt(row['first'], row['second'], row['third']) 
            for row in csv_rows if row['first'] in checklist]
    print(tups)
```

I get the following result:

```
>>> [suminfo(a='check1', b='1', c='1'), suminfo(a='check2', b='2', c='2'), suminfo(a='check3', b='3', c='3')]
```

Comment: 10 bucks says the OP's file is not tab delimited.

Comment: @JaredSmith Sorry to dissapoint but the error seems to have been somewhere else. I just copied my own code and ran in stand-alone and it did what I was expected. Seems to be a silly spelling mistake somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to verify that it works!